# python dataframe combining columns of lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Basically I want to combine dataframe columns with lists, and keep it as a list.

```
df
     a                      b
['2%', '70%']    ['2% W/V', '70% V/V']
['100%']         []
['5%', '60%']    ['5% W/V', '60% V/V']
```

And I want to have:

```
df
        c 
['2% W/V', '70% V/V']
['100%']         
['5% W/V', '60% V/V']
```

I can do this by setting  `df['b']` column to a `str` and use `combine_first`:

```
df = df.astype({"b": str}).copy()
df['b'] = df['b'].replace('[]', np.nan)
df['c'] = df['b'].combine_first(df['a']).copy()
```

But I want to keep it as a list so I can combine it with other columns of lists. I tried using:

`df['c'] = df['b'].combine_first(df['a']).copy()`

Without setting `df['b']` to a `str` but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combine_first function doesn't work with empty list type.

```
    df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: x if x else np.nan)
    df['c'] = df['b'].combine_first(df['a'])
```

It works without setting to str type.